# global variable in Django views.py

Tags: python, django, global-variables

I am new to Django. In views.py I want to use variable defined in one function in anothe function. But when even after defining a variable as global it returns error.
views.py

```
def index(request):
   data = {'Price':[100,200], 'Sale':[30,40]}
   global df
   df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def corr(request):
   correlation = corr.df()
   print(correlation)
```

Error: `name 'df' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Global variable must be set in settings.py

```
df = DataFrame()
```

after import

```
 from django.conf import settings
 seetings.df
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Django Globals

```
pip install django_globals
```

In your project’s settings.py, add django_globals.middleware.Global to MIDDLEWARE (or MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES on Django < 1.10)

Settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',

    'django_globals.middleware.Global',
)
```

Views.py

```
from django_globals import globals
```